# How do I clear local images from Electron's cache when using a preload script?

Tags: caching, electron, chromium

**Edit:** While I still do not understand the differences between the session and webFrame cache, `webFrame.clearCache()` can simply be called from the within the preload script.

**Problem**

I have an Electron application which involves renaming and reordering images on the local filesystem. This often results in files swapping their filenames which causes caching issues that are not resolved until the window is reloaded. I am unable to clear or disable the cache.

**Methods that work (unsatisfactory)**

- Calling `require("electron").webFrame.clearCache();` from within the renderer process. This is not a satisfactory solution as it requires `nodeIntegration` to be enabled. (The `WebFrameMain` class available to the main process does not have a `clearCache` method).
- Checking "Disable cache" from Chrome DevTools. Obviously this is not a solution for production.

**Methods that don't work**

- Clearing the session cache. I noted that the session cache size was always 0.

```
mainWindow.webContents.session.clearCache();
```

- Clearing the session storage data.

```
mainWindow.webContents.session.clearStorageData();
```

- Adding the following command line switches to the main process.

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("disk-cache-size", "0");
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("disable-http-cache");
```

- Providing a session object with cache disabled when creating the window.

```
webPreferences: {
  preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
  session: session.fromPartition("example", { cache: false })
}
```

---

There are clearly components to the caching system I do not understand. It seems that the session cache and webFrame cache must be two different things, and I can not find a way to access the later from the main process or without `nodeIntegration`.

A minimal project which shows this issue can be found here: https://github.com/jacob-c-bickel/electron-clear-cache-test. Clicking the button swaps the filenames of the two images, however no visible change occurs until the window is reloaded.

I am using Electron 13.1.4 and Windows 10 2004.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah – `webFrame` is meant to be used *inside the browser*, so that's usually going to mean `preload.js`. You then can use [Electron's Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) (IPC) techniques to expose that method globally on the `window` object, allowing use elsewhere in your app!

It's like you're carving out a path through each level of your app for access to the right functions.

Altogether, that will look like this:

`preload.js`:

```js
import { contextBridge, webFrame } from 'electron';

export const RendererApi = {
  clearCache() {
    webFrame.clearCache()
  },
};

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", RendererApi);
```

And then anywhere inside your rendering process:

```js
window.api.clearCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to clearCache with `require("electron").webFrame.clearCache();` and attach it to the windows object in your preLoad script, then use that in your isolated renderer.

Google "electron preload"